# Explaining variable scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

This is simple, but I cannot understand why it does not work.

```js
var a = function() {
 console.log(c); // "10" is expecting, but it is not defined
};

var b = function() {
 var c = 10; // local variable, but it is accessibly for b(), I think
 a();
}();
```

Why is variable `c` not defined? And how can I resolve this problem without passing `c` into `b()` as an argument?

Comment: `c` is local to `b`, it's not visible to `a`. `c` needs to exist outside of `b` or you need to pass it to `a`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Comment: Because C live in B and it can not be accessed from outside B

You can pass C as a PARAM

var a = function(c) {
 console.log(c); // "10" is expecting, but it is not defined
};

var b = function() {
 var c = 10; // local variable, but it is accessibly for b(), I think
 a(c);
}();

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```
var c = 0;
var a = function() {
    console.log(c); // "10" is expecting, but it is not defined
};

var b = function() {
    c = 10; // local variable, but it is accessibly for b(), I think
    a();
}();
```

Comment: @RahulDesai sure, in this case it will be undefined

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add parameter to function a

```
var a = function(c) {
    console.log(c); // "10" is expecting, but it is not defined
};

var b = function() {
    var c = 10; // local variable, but it is accessibly for b(), I think
    a(c);
}();
```

Comment: You forgot it too. :)

Comment: This will not work. You are not passing c into a(); and it will return undefined

Comment: Yes lol i've missed that too :))
actually i missed the point of the question :)

Comment: Could also use `console.log(arguments)` at `a` , without declaring possible parameter `c`

Answer (score 1):

The question is better viewed from the other side. Why *would* it be defined? `a` wouldn't really be so reusable with a comment saying "NOTE: You can only run this function if you have a `var c` declared in the encompassing function". That's just not very discoverable, and means it's very hard to track how long a certain naming scope is used.

A feature of JavaScript that may do what you desire is "*closures*". This is when you declare an entire function inside of another; it's very handy for callbacks when you don't feel the second function deserves its own naming and place in the code structure.

What will happen here is that the language will automatically see that it needs `c` (already declared) inside of the function you're declaring, and so it preserves an internal reference to it, associated with the `callbackFunction` variable. So, you can still refer to it in there.

```
var b = function() {
    var c = 10; // local variable, but it is accessibly for b(), I think
        var callbackFunction = function() {
           console.log(c);
        };
        // optionally, place c in a setTimeout, ajax callback, etc.
    callbackFunction();
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `a` has a new scope in which `c` isn't defined. You could define `var c = 0;` outside of `a` or pass `c` as argument to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

function inherits parent scope where it was declared, not where it was called. All functions inherit window scope, so you can just make variable c global.

```
var a = function() {
    console.log(c); // "10" is expecting, but it is not defined
};

var b = function() {
    c = 10; // local variable, but it is accessibly for b(), I think
    a();
}();
```